# elif not working in python code for creating a password

Tags: python

I'm new to python. Whenever I use "`elif`" it says that it's invalid syntax. Can someone please help with solving the problem?

```
repeat = True
while repeat:
 password = input("Please enter a password: ")
 if (len(password)) <8:
       choice = input ("Your password needs to have at least 8 letters. 1 = Try Again, 2 = Exit: ")
       if choice == "2":
        repeat = False
 else:
    print ("That is a valid password.")
    exit
 elif not any(char.isdigit() for char in password):
      choice = input ("Your password needs to have at least 1 number in it. 1 = Try Again, 2 = Exit: ")
      if choice == "2":
       repeat = False
 else:
     print ("That is a valid password.")
     break
```

Comment: Please format your post: select the code and type `ctrl-k`.

Comment: You have an `else` before the `elif`. How do you think the `elif` will ever be reached?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement

Answer (score 5):

An elif block needs to immediately follow an if block or another elif block. Your elif follows an else block. That is not allowed in python. Fixing it very easy, just remove the first else block:

```
repeat = True
while repeat:
 password = input("Please enter a password: ")
 if (len(password)) <8:
       choice = input ("That is not a valid password.\nYour password needs to have at least 8 letters. 1 = Try Again, 2 = Exit: ")
       if choice == "2":
        repeat = False
 elif not any(char.isdigit() for char in password):
      choice = input ("That is not a valid password.\nYour password needs to have at least 1 number in it. 1 = Try Again, 2 = Exit: ")
      if choice == "2":
       repeat = False
 else:
     print ("That is a valid password.")
     break
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [[Python]: The if statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#elif):

> ```
> if_stmt ::=  "if" expression ":" suite
>              ( "elif" expression ":" suite )*
>              ["else" ":" suite]
> ```

`elif` can't come after `else`. Removing your 1<sup>st</sup> `else` clause, fixed the problem (I also did a bit of code and output formatting):

```
repeat = True

while repeat:
    password = input("Please enter a password: ")
    if len(password) <8:
        choice = input("Your password needs to have at least 8 letters.\n1 = Try Again\n2 = Exit:\n")
        if choice == "2":
            repeat = False
    elif not any(char.isdigit() for char in password):
        choice = input("Your password needs to have at least 1 number in it.\n1 = Try Again\n2 = Exit:\n")
        if choice == "2":
            repeat = False
    else:
        print ("That is a valid password.")
        break
```